# Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Unexpected byte found when reading an object

Tags: java

i have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_picture")

public class Picture implements Serializable {


    private Integer idPicture;
    private String link;
    private Product product;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;....................}
```

i need to show the picture's list by product So, i have this method

```
 @Override  public List<Picture> findByProduct(Product p) {         
    return 
    em.createQuery("select p from Picture p where
    s.product=:x",Picture.class).
                 setParameter("x",p)
                     .getResultList();  
 }
```

So when i run , i get this exception

> Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException:
>       java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Unexpected byte found when reading
>       an object: 254    at
>       org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:236
>         at
>        org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181

Comment: Does this class have a `readObject()` or `writeObject()` or `writeReplace()` or `readResolve()` method?

Comment: no, i didn't use this methods

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I had a problem of not mentioning the `class` when I was using above methods. This could also be a problem with type resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Got here by Google, after searching about the same error message.
In my case, the error was known for a Jboss Client Bug as mention [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/228686).

BUT! after a long tracing I found that i mixed used of a same name class "A" with the same package name "com.abc.def" but from difference source.

The first class "com.abc.def.A" was from EJB interface.
The second class "com.abc.def.A" was from my dynamic web project.

Since assigning different class from the same name and package was not a compile error, so its really pain in the butt.